# How to print the vowels of the input str without duplicates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is my code thus far, it duplicates vowels e.g.:

- Input: `baloon`
- Current output: `a,o,o`
- Expected output: `a,o`

How can I fix this?

```js
function printOutVowels(str) {
  let vowels = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == "a" || str[i] == "e" || str[i] == "i" || str[i] == "o" || str[i] == "u") {
      vowels = str[i]
      console.log(vowels);
    }
  }
}

printOutVowels("timidity");
```

Comment: Hi Nathaniel, welcome.. your code will now log every instance of each vowel, so you'll see doubles. In this case I'd put an array of 0..255 of byte, and first count every char occurrence. Then in a *second* loop, you can pick up a[65], a[69] etcetera  when >0.

Comment: And yes, first convert the input string to lowercase so that it is not case sensitive

Comment: You can add your vowels in an array like `found=[]` then `found.push(str[i])` and test in the 'if' it's in the array : `if( !found.includes(str[i]) && (/*your other tests there*/) )`. You can do the same with an object : `found = {}` then `found[str[i]] = true` and `if( !(str[i] in found) && (/*your other tests there*/))` The later is faster since you build an index instead of constantly searching into an array.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) data structure. A set is like an array, but contains no duplicated element.

```js
function printOutVowels(str) {
  // Create an empty set
  const vowels = new Set();
  
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == "a" || str[i] == "e" || str[i] == "i" || str[i] == "o" || str[i] == "u") {
      // Add element to the set
      vowels.add(str[i]);
    }
  }

  // Print the set content
  for (let item of vowels) {
    console.log(item);
  }
}

printOutVowels("timidity");
```

Behind the scene, `Set` use its [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) method to check if an item is already in the set. This method is faster than [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) when a set and an array have the same size.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that :

```
function printOutVowels(str){
    let vowels = "aeiou";
    let output = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
      if(str.toLowerCase().includes(vowels[i])) output += vowels[i];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Splitting and filtering is a concise way to get the vowels. Running them through a set will enforce uniqueness.  (Force to lowercase to handle both cases)

```js
function vowels(str) {
  const isVowel = l => /^[aeiou]$/.test(l);
  const vowels = new Set(str.toLowerCase().split('').filter(isVowel));
  return Array.from(vowels.values());
}

console.log(vowels('TIMidity'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `String.prototype.concat(...new Set("baloon"))` or `[...new Set("baloon")]`

```js
function printOutVowels(str) {
  let vowels = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == "a" || str[i] == "e" || str[i] == "i" || str[i] == "o" || str[i] == "u") {
      vowels = str[i]
      console.log(vowels);
    }
  }
}

printOutVowels(String.prototype.concat(...new Set("baloon")));
```

**METHOD 2**

```js
function printOutVowels(str) {
  let vowels = /[aeiou]/gi;
  let result = str.match(vowels);
  console.log(result.filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index).join("\n"))
}

printOutVowels("baloon");
printOutVowels("tomorow");
printOutVowels("india");
```

**METHOD 3**

Using `[...new Set(array)].join("\n")`

```js
function printOutVowels(str) {
  let vowels = /[aeiou]/gi;
  let result = str.match(vowels);
  console.log([...new Set(result)].join("\n"))
}

printOutVowels("baloon");
printOutVowels("tomorow");
printOutVowels("india");
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function printOutVowels(str){
    str =  [...new Set(str.toLowerCase())];
    const vowelsList = str.filter(item=> "aeiou".includes(item));
    return vowelsList.join('');
}
console.log(printOutVowels("timidityee"))
```

Comment: toLowerCase() to handle big letters and small letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array and push a vowel each time you find a new one. With that, you can prevent duplicate items by using `includes`.

```
function printOutVowels(str) {
  let vowels = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (
      (str[i] == "a" ||
        str[i] == "e" ||
        str[i] == "i" ||
        str[i] == "o" ||
        str[i] == "u") &&
      !vowels.includes(str[i])
    ) {
      vowels.push(str[i]);
      console.log(vowels);
    }
  }
}

printOutVowels("timidityoou");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function printOutVowels(str) {
  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == "a" || str[i] == "e" || str[i] == "i" || str[i] == "o" || str[i] == "u") {
      result += str[i]
    }
  }
  return (result.replace(/(.)\1+/g, "$1"))
}

console.log(printOutVowels("timidity"));
console.log(printOutVowels("tomorrow"));
console.log(printOutVowels("aaaeeeiiiooouu"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```js
function printOutVowels(str) {
  var vowelsArray = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  var presentvowel = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < vowelsArray.length; i++) {
    if (str.toLowerCase().includes(vowelsArray[i])) {
      presentvowel.push(vowelsArray[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(presentvowel);
}

printOutVowels("aaabbbccee");
```

Answer (score 0):

This alternate technique uses a regular expression to match vowels that occur only once by using a negative lookahead assertion on the backreference match.  This keeps the *last* occurrence of each repeated vowel as opposed to the first occurrence.  (You didn't specify the order.)

```js
printOutVowels = str => str.match(/([aeiou])(?!.*\1)/gi).join('');
console.log(printOutVowels('baloon'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with after what I've learnt from you all.

```
function printOutVowels(str){
    let vowels = "aeiou";
    let vowelsFound = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++){
        if(str.includes(vowels[i])){
          vowelsFound += vowels[i] + " ";
        }
    }
    console.log("Vowels:", vowelsFound);
}
printOutVowels("baloon");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set` which will eliminate duplicates

```js
function printOutVowels(str) {
  let vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"];
  console.log([...new Set(str.split("").filter(char => vowels.includes(char.toLowerCase())))])
}

printOutVowels("timidity")
printOutVowels("baloon")
printOutVowels("tEeEEeSt")
```